# How to parse Java sources?

Tags: java, startswith

I have a question:
i develop tiny webapp (Java) that parse, compile user sources, run several admin-defined tests and return response - user sources successful passed all tests, compilation fails or execution  was terminated because of time limit. So for compilation i need to know what is class of user's code (`public class SomeClass`). Here is my code:

```
String source = task.method;
StringReader sourceReader = new StringReader(source);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(sourceReader);

String labClassName = null;
while (labClassName == null) {
    String line = reader.readLine();

    if (line.startsWith("public")) {

        Scanner classNameScanner = new Scanner(line).useDelimiter("\\s");
        classNameScanner.next();
        classNameScanner.next();
        labClassName = classNameScanner.next();
    }
}

reader.close();
```

As for me this is quite ugly construction, but it works, i retrieve necessary classname, but i feel that there are other more convenient ways to find some string which starts with "public class" after several imports. Here is one of examples of user's sources (sources are quite different, some of them starts with simple "public class", some starts with imports, quantity of imports is random - only necessary for this code):

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class ISToIteratorAdapter implements Iterator<Byte> {

    public ISToIteratorAdapter(InputStream is) {
        this.is = is;
        try {
            this.last = is.read();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private final InputStream is;
    private int last = -1;

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return last != -1;
    }

    @Override
    public Byte next() {
        try {
            if (last != -1) {
                int tmp = last;
                last = is.read();
                return (byte) tmp;
            } else {
                throw new NoSuchElementException();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

Comment: This sounds rather fanciful. If you know the class name: what then? You'll also have to know the package, if any, at least for invocation. How would you know the constructor and methods to call? What if it is abstract? And so on...

Comment: If you can compile the class, you should know the name anyway. I'll also give you `public final class SomeClass`.

Comment: Don't bother. Too hard. Have the user tell you.

Comment: i don't use packages. My task is only to TEST user class with tests, for my test i need to know the class name. This webapp is quite simple, not for real code, but for testing students code.About "public final class" - this is good idea, so i need to find "class" at first and then determine classname, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can expect the source file not to contain any "evasive action" or tricks to trip your code, then

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile( "^\\s*public\\s+class\\s+(\\w+).*$" );

String line = reader.readLine();
Matcher mat = pat.matcher( line );
if( mat.matches() ){
    String classname = mat.group( 1 );
    // ...
}
```

will find a line that contains spaces, keywords "public" and "class" and the class name.